# Mock class with constructor that takes IConfiguration as parameter

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I want to mock class IncidentData.

The class with constructor:

```cs
public class IncidentData
{
    public IncidentData(IConfiguration configurationRoot)
    {
        configurationRoot.GetSection("CarambaAttributeData").Bind(this);
    }
}
```

I've tried to send setup a mock like so:

```cs
var incidentDataMock = new Mock<IncidentData>();
incidentDataMock.Setup(x => It.IsAny<IConfiguration>());
```

This gets me "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range"

Should I mock IConfiguration? How do I do that? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve by mocking that class?

As for the error, you would need to pass the argument when creating the mock

For example

```
//...

IConfiguration config = Mock.Of<IConfiguration>();
var incidentDataMock = new Mock<IncidentData>(config); //<--NOTE constructor argument passed.

//...
```

or using an actual `IConfiguration` instance

```
//...

IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    //...all extensions here
    //...
    .Build();
var incidentDataMock = new Mock<IncidentData>(config); //<--NOTE constructor argument passed.

//...
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the library

Comment: I'm trying to create a simple mock of IncidentData to pass into another constructor.

The IConfiguration instance is a potential solution, I suppose, if the actual configuration has to be "real".

Comment: So why not just create an instance of the subject class manually and pass in the mock configuration? But either way, injecting IConfiguration indicates to me that they are code smells that will cause problem further down the road. Hence my XY statement

Comment: Right! I will create the the instance and take it up with my colleagues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you are looking for a way to mock the `configurationRoot` parameter of the ctor instead of the whole `IncidentData` class.

All you need to do is create a memory collection then register a memory collection provider for the configuration instance.

```
var carambaAttributeDataConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   {"CarambaAttributeData:Key1", "Value1"},
   {"CarambaAttributeData:Key2", "Value2"},
   ...
   {"CarambaAttributeData:KeyN", "ValueN"},
};

IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(carambaAttributeDataConfig)
    .Build();

var incidentDataMock = new IncidentData(config);
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#memory-configuration-provider)